# variable set to true in setTimeout is always false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

Ok, I think I have a `this` context issue. I am trying to make, only on mousedown and the timer is reset on mouseup, a timer set in motion so that a boolean flag turns true after 5 seconds. If it is true when the timer is reset (on mouseup), a function `this.triggerRoomChange()` is triggered.

Here's what I have (its node):

```
   clearRoomChange(){

    this.readyToChangeRooms = true;
    console.log('READY');
  };

  onMouseDown()
  {

    this.mousedownTimeout = setTimeout(this.clearRoomChange, 5000);
    this.mouseDown++;
  }
  onMouseUp()
  {
    clearTimeout(this.mousedownTimeout);

    console.log(this.readyToChangeRooms);
    if(this.readyToChangeRooms)
    {
      this.triggerRoomChange();
      this.readyToChangeRooms = false;
    }
    this.mouseDown--;
  }
```

The print READY fires after the 5 seconds and the setTimeout appears to be cleared, however the variable (when printed on `MouseUp`) is always false. I clearly set it to true in `this.clearRoomChange`

Whats going on?

Comment: scope of the timeout is window

Comment: so I should do this.setTimeout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout changes the scope. So you need to use bind to maintain scope

```
this.mousedownTimeout = setTimeout(this.clearRoomChange.bind(this), 5000);
```